# What to do about storing user uploaded files in a Zend Framework application?

Tags: php, zend-framework, web-applications, file-upload

I'm creating a web application that will involve habitual file uploading and retrieval (PDFs, Word Documents, etc).

Here are the requirements:

- need to be able to link to them in my view script so a user can download the files.
- files should not be accessible to users who are not logged in.

**Question #1: Where should I store these files?**

1. On the file system?

   - Does this mean an `uploads` directory in my `public` directory?
   - I also want it to be easy for me to deploy a new version of my application when changes are made to the code. Currently I have a process where I upload my application in a directory titled with the current date (i.e. `2009-12-01`) and create a sym link to it titled `current`. This would mean that the `uploads` directory would need to be outside of this directory so it could be shared among all the different versions of the application, regardless of which one is being used at the time.
2. In the database?

   - I could store the file contents in the database and serve them up when a user requests to download them. This would keep the files in my application secure from non-authorized users, but I could achieve the same result once I create a controller to do this work.
   - This would solve the issue of having to sym link.
   - However, this might be bad practice (storing file contents in a database in addition to information).

What do you think I should do?

### Solution:

Here's what I ended up doing:

I deploy a new version of my application, and create a symlink to the version I would like to use:

```
/server/myapp/releases/2009-12-15
/server/myapp/current -> /server/myapp/releases/2009-12-15
```

I created a directory above my application directory, and a symlink to that directory in my application:

```
/server/uploads
/server/myapp/current/application/data/uploads -> /server/uploads
```

I defined an `APPLICATION_UPLOADS_DIR` variable in my `/public/index.php` file:

```
// Define path to uploads directory
defined('APPLICATION_UPLOADS_DIR')
    || define('APPLICATION_UPLOADS_DIR', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../data/uploads'));
```

And used this variable in my upload form to set the directory to upload to:

```
<?php

class Default_Form_UploadFile extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        //excerpt

        $file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('file');
        $file->setLabel('File to upload:')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->setDestination(APPLICATION_UPLOADS_DIR);
    }
}
```

In my controller, I rename the file to something unique so it can't be overwritten by a file with the same name. I save the unique filename, original filename, and mime-type in the database so I can use it later:

```
public function uploadAction()
{
    //...excerpt...form has already been validated

    $originalFilename = pathinfo($form->file->getFileName());
    $newFilename = 'file-' . uniqid() . '.' . $originalFilename['extension'];
    $form->file->addFilter('Rename', $newFilename);

    try {
        $form->file->receive();
        //upload complete!

        $file = new Default_Model_File();
        $file->setDisplayFilename($originalFilename['basename'])
            ->setActualFilename($newFilename)
            ->setMimeType($form->file->getMimeType())
            ->setDescription($form->description->getValue());
        $file->save();

        return $this->_helper->FlashMessenger(array('success'=>'The file has been uploaded.'));

    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        //error
    }
}
```

To download the files, I created a download action which retrieves the file and sends it to the user with the help of [Noginn's SendFile Action Helper](http://www.noginn.com/2009/03/08/sending-files-with-the-zend-framework/).

```
public function downloadAction()
{
    //user already has permission to download the file
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout(); //won't work if you don't do this
    $file = $this->_getFileFromRequest();
    $location = APPLICATION_UPLOADS_DIR . '/' . $file->getActualFilename();
    $mimeType = $file->getMimeType();
    $filename = $file->getDisplayFilename();
    $this->_helper->sendFile($location, $mimeType, array(
        'disposition' => 'attachment',
        'filename' => $filename
    ));
}
```

To offer a download link in the view script, I point them to the download action with the file id param:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array(
    'controller'=>'files',
    'action'=>'download',
    'file'=>$file->id)); ?>"><?php echo $file->displayFilename; ?></a>
```

That's it! If you have any other advice or criticisms of this method, please post your answers/comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symlinking to a directory outside web root as Pascal suggested is a good solution. One way to do it, especially if you need some kind of user access control over the files, would be to use a php script to serve those files. You could have a download controller/action etc. that takes the file name as a parameter, then loads the file from some directory outside web root and outputs it. Then you would also need to send some headers before the file itself so the browser knows what to do with it. Headers could be set file type specific or just the generic "octet-stream" to force browser to show the download dialog.

Comment: I recommend this helper for sending files to the browser: http://www.noginn.com/2009/03/08/sending-files-with-the-zend-framework/

Comment: There are many types of headers you can set that are related to this and the right combination depends on the specific use case. Most important is the Content-Type header, which tells the browser what type of content you are serving. "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" is in my experience a good generic way to force a download but you can set headers specific for different file types. Then there are also headers like transfer encoding, cache, file size and filename. You can check out some examples in the comments here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php or search in Google

Answer (score 2):

To allow users to diretly download files, two solutions :

- have your files in a sub-directory of your website *(what you are already doing)*, which is often required by applications
- have your files in either :

  - another separate virtual host, that only serves those static files (no versionning, there)
  - Or, I suppose an Apache [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) would do, too, actually -- the example in Apache's manual looks a bit like your situation ^^

About your second point with versionned directories : what I often do is :

- store the files in a directory that's not under the application directory (`/var/www` for instance) ; say `/var/media`
- create a symbolink link that points to that directory :

  - `/var/www/media` points to `/var/media`
  - this can be done with something like `ln -s /var/media /var/www/media`
- there creation of that symlink is quite fast, and can be done each time you have a new version of your application

  - and you can have several versions of your application that all point to the same directory.

This works nice, is easy to deploy, and "tricks" the application into thinking the files are in one of its sub-directories -- even if it's not physicaly the case.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to store it in you app tree - you can store it elsewhere and configure your web server to point /uploads virtual dir to that place (Alias in Apache, Virtual directory in IIS - most webservers have it), and have the application link to /uploads. You can of course use symlinks too. 
Having separate directory would also allow you to share it in case you would have more than one server running the same application.